# DisposeAsync method deadlocks when shutting down a .NET Core App

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5, idisposable

In my `.NET 5` console app I have a class that implements `IAsyncDisposable`, because it needs to call an async shutdown method of a third-party library, something like this:

```
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
   {
        await thirdParyLib.ShutDownAsync();
   }
```

This works without issues when using the class with the classic `using` statement.

However, when I register the class in .NET Core's Dependency Injection mechanism (as a singleton), I'm having problems.

In particular, when the .NET Core application stops the DI framework automatically (and correctly) calls `DisposeAsync()` on all singleton instances that are registered. This would be perfect, but the problem is that at that point the code hangs here:

```
await thirdParyLib.ShutDownAsync();
```

I'm assuming the thread is deadlocked, but I don't know how to further diagnose and solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of application are you building? ASP.NET Core has no synchronization context so `await` won't block. Desktop and Blazor apps do, so they'll block if the original sync context is busy, eg blocked while waiting something else.

Comment: You can use a debugger to see which threads are stuck and at which code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: it is indeed a desktop app, so I guess you're probably right. In this case I guess the correct approach is to cancel all other thread that are accessing the object before trying to dispose?

Comment: @Master_T without knowing what the other threads are doing, and how that interacts with `ShutDownAsync()` - we could only speculate. Can you hint what `thirdPartyLib` is here? or: make it your vendors problem (i.e. ask them why it is blocking, and how to fix it)?

Comment: @Master_T the quick&dirty solution is to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. BUT this is an unusual situation - a console application doesn't have a sync context and shouldn't block. A desktop app (WinForms, WPF) does but even then, why is the UI thread blocked? Do you have code that blocks on exit?

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks for your suggestion, I assumed the problem was in my code, but In after your comment I searched a bit about the library I'm using (it's `PuppeteerSharp`, a web automation tool). And after a bit of searching, I might have found the issue, it might be this: https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1354 - thanks again for your comment, I will read about the issue and see if it's the case here.

Comment: @Master_T well, that issue shows a sync-over-async, which is *never* a good idea, and is notorious for deadlocks; it *could* be related, but I wouldn't assume such, since you're on the async path here

Comment: @MarcGravell: honestly I'm not the biggest parallelism expert, I must confess, but indeed I wasn't using `.Wait()`, I was using `await` properly. However, in that thread they suggest calling `.Dispose()` directly instead of manually calling `.CloseAsync()` like I was doing. I tested this and the code is not hanging anymore, so that's good enough for me at the moment. Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem I would suggest that you specify and tag the problematic library in the question and write an answer yourself, if you think the solution could be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution in my specific case, which was to directly call `Dispose()` on the third-party object, rather than the dedicated async method that was being problematic.